# asana getUserInfo error using PHP

Tags: php

this is my code

```
<?php 
require_once('asana.php');

$asana = new Asana(array('apiKey' => 'XXXXXXXX')); // API Key

$userinfo=$asana->getUserInfo();

if ($asana->responseCode != '200' || is_null($userinfo)) {
    echo 'Error while trying to connect to Asana, response code: ' . $asana->responseCode;
    return;
}
 $resultJson = json_decode($userinfo);

foreach ($resultJson->data as $user) {
    echo  $user->name . ' (id ' . $user->id . ')' .  PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

In asana.php

```
public function getUserInfo($userId = null, array $opts = array()) {
        $options = http_build_query($opts);

        if (is_null($userId)) {
            $userId = 'me';
        }

        return $this->askAsana($this->userUrl . '/' . $userId . '?' . $options);
    }
```

And I got error like this: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\pngtest\index.php on line 15

What is the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like your `$user` variable is not an object, yet you reference it like it is: `$user->name`. What does `var_dump($user)` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$resultJson = json_decode($userinfo);

foreach ($resultJson->data as $user) {
}
```

You're trying to access  `$resultJson->data` before you know if `$resultJson` is a valid object or not.

Note that [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

It is possible (likely) that `$resultJson` is NULL, because it was given invalid JSON data. You should `echo $userinfo` and determine if it is what you expect.